# Generics as method return type

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to do the following:

```
    Class MyClass{
      Public ArrayList Query(String queryName ) {
          ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
         if (queryName =="query1") { 
           ClassA objA1 = new ClassA();
           ClassA objA2 = new ClassA();
           ....//logic to populate the object
           items.add( objA1 ); 
           items.add( objA2 ); 
          }
         elseif (queryName =="query1") {  
           ClassB objB1 = new ClassB();
           ClassB objB2 = new ClassB();
           ....//logic to populate the object
           items.add( objB1 ); 
           items.add( objB2 ); 

          }
         return items.
     }
    }
```

Now, to use Generic for the ArrayList, E.g.
         ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
But I cannot do that since return parameter can be of any one type. How can I use generics for method return type in this case?
MyClass has method 'Query' and ClassA and ClassB are inner-classes of MyClass. The idea is to write a query implementation at root level class, which will accept queryName, trigger the query and return the instances(List/Table) of the inner-class objects which are relevant for the query. 
The above code represents a logical representation only.

Comment: This doesn't look like Java.

Comment: String equality can't be tested that way, are classa and classb related through an interface or supertype more narrow then object? If so, use that. If not, use object.

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi Yes, though it's slightly different if ClassA and ClassB are subclasses of the same parent.

Comment: @ElliotFrisch I though Java 1.7 allowed for direct string comparison without `equals`?

Comment: Bug alert: `queryName =="query1"` - see [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/256196)

Comment: guys, question is not about correct syntax, rather its about approach to solve the mentioned problem. As already mentioned, The above code represents a logical representation only. Could you help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general answer, since your question is a bit unclear what you are trying to do, I will explain the question of the title. If you want generics as return type, you have to define it in that way:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> query(final T object) {
  final ArrayList<T> ts = new ArrayList<>();
  ts.add(object);
  return ts;
}
```

Now you can call this method with

```
final ArrayList<ClassA> query = query(new ClassA());
```

or

```
final ArrayList<ClassB> query = query(new CLassB());
```

Comment: could you check the question now